# How do i compare two double type 2D arrays with eachother?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment to write a program to make a chart of measurements (which are generated with `math.random`). This part is done and all functioning but the next step is to point out in which column the max value is in.

I began to make a new 2d array which is exactly the same as the first and then sorting it using `Arrays.sort` so I knew what value was the highest.

I then tried to write code that compared all the values in the first array with the max value I got.
(I used a for-loop so when the values matched I would know the position of the highest value)
But this does not work,

This is whats comes up:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [D
> cannot be cast to class java.lang.Comparable ([D and
> java.lang.Comparable are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
> at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:320)
> at java.base/java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:188)
> at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1040)"

I'm very open to all suggestions and help I can get! Also if you need me to show the code I wrote let me know!

Otherwise, have a great day!

EDIT:
This is my written code for the last part.

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(peak);

double peak2 = peak[x][y];

//Testing for highest value

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{

  for (int k = 0; k < y; k++)
  {

double value2 = value[k][i];

    if (value2 == peak2)
    {
     System.out.println("The highest value: " + peak2 + "is in cell " + i + ", " + k);
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should always post your code, so we can see where the error could be coming from.

Comment: Arrays.deepEquals(multiArray1,multiArray2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for sorting. Just iterate through the array and locate the maximum value.

```java
double maxVal = peak[0][0];
int maxRow = 0;
int maxCol = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < peak.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < peak[row].length; col++) {
        if (peak[row][col] > maxVal) {
            maxVal = peak[row][col];
            maxRow = row;
            maxCol = col;
        }
    }
}
System.out.printf("The highest value: %f is in cell %d, %d%n",
                  maxVal,
                  maxRow,
                  maxCol);
```